# ASP.NET MVC 5 Insert statement conflict FK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I building simple project just for self-study and i have a little problem.
Im using Visual Studio and Entity Framework.

I builded a ASP.NET MVC 5 app where are CRUD functionality.
In database is connection between 2 tables like on
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRt3R.png)

HTTP POST bellow from CarController

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save(Car car)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var viewModel = new CarFormViewModel()
                {
                    Cars = car,
                    CarTypeModels = _context.CarTypeModels.ToList()
                };
                return View("CarForm", viewModel);
            }


            if (car.Id == 0)
                _context.Cars.Add(car);
            else
            {
                var customerInDb = _context.Cars.Single(c => c.Id == car.Id);
                customerInDb.Name = car.Name;
                customerInDb.HorsePower = car.HorsePower;
                customerInDb.LinkToImage = car.LinkToImage;
                customerInDb.CarTypeModelId = car.CarTypeModelId;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Car");
        }
```

Im getting an error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uw9d.png)

Db.CarTypeModel ->

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CarTypeModels] (
[Id]   TINYINT        NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CarTypeModels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

db.Car ->

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars] (
[Id]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]           NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
[HorsePower]     INT            NOT NULL,
[LinkToImage]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[CarTypeModelId] TINYINT        DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Cars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Cars_dbo.CarTypeModels_CarTypeModelId] FOREIGN KEY ([CarTypeModelId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CarTypeModels] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE); GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CarTypeModelId] ON [dbo].[Cars]([CarTypeModelId] ASC);
```

And code from CarForm which using CarTypeModelId

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cars.CarTypeModelId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cars.CarTypeModelId, new SelectList(Model.CarTypeModels, "ID", "Name"), "Select car type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cars.CarTypeModelId)
</div>
```

I have API Connection and its working fine. I think a problem is in CarController but I really dont know where...

```
//POST /api/cars
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCar(CarDto carDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var car = Mapper.Map<CarDto, Car>(carDto);
        _context.Cars.Add(car);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        carDto.Id = car.Id;

        return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + car.Id), carDto);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your dropdown list selection doesnt work properly and returns car.CarTypeModelId= 0. Try to fix the dropdown list by replacing "ID" by "Id" :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cars.CarTypeModelId, new SelectList(Model.CarTypeModels, "Id", "Name"), "Select car type", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I tried this and it isnt this, but I found a solution. In CarFormView which Im using in Save function where little bug. In DB I have table names Car, and in CarFormView.                                                           public class CarFormViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CarTypeModel> CarTypeModels { get;set;}
        public Car Cars { get; set; }
    }  and I rename Cars to Car and it resolve my problem.